# how to check which storage accounts are linked with the azure logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-logic-apps

We have plenty of logic apps and storage accounts but while creating logic app, we can see the available storage accounts in that location:

[image]

But our logic apps are named like:
[image]

When we check the storage account file shares, it is named with different at the end of the connected application:

[image]

**Is there any other way to check which logic app is linked with the storage account either using Portal or Command line?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage account gets created for **Standard** logic app as **Hosting** option is available only when creating a Standard logic app.

[image]

- There is no **Hosting** tab for **Consumption** logic app.

[image]

- You can check the storage account name from the value of **`AzureWebJobsStorage`** in Portal.

[image]

- I have used the below command to get the storage account name linked with the standard logic app.

```bash
az logicapp config appsettings list --name <logicAppName> -g <resourceGroup> --query "[?name=='AzureWebJobsStorage'].value" --out tsv | Select-String -Pattern 'AccountName=[^;]*' | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[0].Value.Split('=')[1] }
```